# Can I install new packages for texlive

Tags: texlive

It seems that I can not do anything to update this outdated TeXlive+Kile system.

```
********:~/TeX$ texhash
texhash: /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R: no write permission. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN: no write permission. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE: no write permission. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R: no write permission. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
```

Comment: Try running `texhash` as root.

Comment: If you are an administrator on your system and you're on linux, you could try `sudo texhash`

Comment: Myname is not in the sudoers file. I am not the root. I can only modify /home/myname folder.

Comment: In that case, if you have a couple of gigabytes in your home directory then you could install a completely fresh version of TeXLive there and just use that, ignoring the system installed version with impunity.

Comment: or ask the administrator to install the package you need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install the file in `~/texmf/tex/latex/<package name>` then it will be found by
the system without running `texhash`. You can control the `TEXMFHOME` value by

```
echo $TEXMFHOME
```

it should point to your home directory

Comment: TeX Live usually doesn't use environment variables, so you should use `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME` instead. And `texhash` is not required for the home tree.

Comment: depends to your installation. And that texhash isn't needed for TEXMFHOME was already mentioned ... :-)

Comment: Indeed, I should actually read the posts. I've only noticed the word "texhash" :-)