# almost APA formatting?

Tags: apa-style

I need to make a fairly large report. It requires a cherry-picked APA style, meaning that it uses some of it, and other things are not APA-compliant. I think I won't have problems dealing with the font, margins and spacing.

My question is how to modify the `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection` to match APA if I use a class like `article` or `report`. One of the most important requirements is that this APA compliant outline shows in the table of contents.

I don't think customizing `apa` or `apa6e` is possible/practical. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you copy the definitions of the `\section`, etc commands from the apa.cls documentclass file to whatever class file you're building?

Comment: Alternatively, if you have the actual APA specifications, you can probably set up the sectioning easily using the `titlesec` package. There are plenty of examples on the site of its use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A practical and quick approach would be to modify the `apa6e` class. The class is rather short being only about 130 lines of code, as it uses a lot of packages to implement the APA style guidelines. The class is also well documented.

You will need to load either the report or preferably the book class rather than the original article class that apa6e.cls is based on. In the `apa6e.cls` file
change line  47 from:

```
 \LoadClass[12pt]{article}
```

to

```
 \LoadClass[12pt]{book}
```

Do the same for whatever else you need to modify.

I would preferably though, change the `.dtx` file rather than the `.cls` file, in order to document the class properly.

Don't forget to acknowledge the original author's contribution, if you distribute your files.

Comment: I have never edited a class before. Is there a particular folder where it should go?

Comment: @ravl1084 As long as is on the default path tree, is ok. To start with, save it in your working directory. First find the original `apa6e.dtx` and `apa6e.ins` files and saved them under different names. When you edit the .dtx you need to Latex the .ins file as well, if you read through the files you will see where you need to edit the class name. If you have any problems, just post a comment or a new question.

Comment: I edited the class and got a new `.cls`. I made a folder in the same place where `apa6e` is and put it there, but running latexmk, it is not found. Is there a command to update the list of `.cls` files?

Comment: @ravl1084 Have a look at this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14678/963