# How to install system wide packages without requiring an ls-R database (with texlive)?

Tags: installing, texlive, best-practices, texmf

### Question

How can I install packages for system-wide use, but without requiring the `ls-R` database to be updated?

### Background

The [texlive documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html) indicates that user specific packages should be placed in `TEXMFHOME` while packages for multiple users should be placed in `TEXMFLOCAL` (both of which are organized by the [TeX Directory Structure](http://www.tug.org/tds/tds.html) (TDS)).

On your system, these locations can be found by using `kpsewhich` (they are configured as part of the installation, *not* just as environmental variables):

```
kpsewhich -expand-var '$TEXMFHOME'    
kpsewhich -expand-var '$TEXMFLOCAL'
```

As pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14678/6903), the `TEXMFHOME` solution does not require the `ls-R` database to be updated: packages can just be added here and they will be found.

The `TEXMFLOCAL` location, however, [requires that](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-370003.4.6) `mktexlsr` (`texhash`) be run to update the `ls-R` database (which must be done as `root` if permissions are properly set).

Is there a similar location to `TEXMFHOME` that *does not* require an `ls-R` database for system-wide use?

The use case is that a user on a shared system maintains a package that we host in `TEXMFLOCAL`.  Whenever they change the names of files, the local `ls-R` database needs to be updated by an administrator. How can we allow the user to modify the package – including changing file names if needed – without requiring an admin to update `ls-R`?

I realize that there will be a performance hit if the database is not used, a separate tree should probably be used. Also, I am sure that the settings for `TEXMFLOCAL` could probably be adjusted (by [removing it from the `TEXMFDBS`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21463/6903)?) to obviate the need for `ls-R`, but I am looking for a "standard" solution that meshes with the documented `texlive` system behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Path expansion and database search are documented in the `kpathsea` and `web2c` documentation (both available with `texdoc`).

Quoting the kpathsea manual (section 3.4.1):

> If a particular path element begins with ‘!!’, however, only the database will be searched for that element, never the disk.

Studying `texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` we find

```
% TEXMFLOCAL follows TEXMFMAIN (and precedes TEXMFDIST) because the
% files in TEXMFMAIN are tightly coupled with the particular version of
% the distribution, such as configuration files.  Overriding them would
% be more likely to cause trouble than help.  On the other hand, the
% bulk of packages and fonts are in TEXMFDIST, and locally-installed
% versions should take precedence over those -- although it is generally
% a source of confusion to have different versions of a package
% installed, whatever the trees, so try to avoid it.
TEXMF = {$TEXMFCONFIG,$TEXMFVAR,$TEXMFHOME,!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFMAIN,!!$TEXMFLOCAL,!!$TEXMFDIST}

% Where to look for ls-R files.  There need not be an ls-R in the
% directories in this path, but if there is one, Kpathsea will use it.
% By default, this is only the !! elements of TEXMF, so that mktexlsr
% does not create ls-R files in the non-!! elements -- because if an
% ls-R is present, it will be used, and the disk will not be searched.
% This is arguably a bug in kpathsea.
TEXMFDBS = {!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFMAIN,!!$TEXMFLOCAL,!!$TEXMFDIST}
```

It should be enough (I haven't tested it), to put the lines

```
TEXMF = {$TEXMFCONFIG,$TEXMFVAR,$TEXMFHOME,!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFMAIN,$TEXMFLOCAL,!!$TEXMFDIST}
TEXMFDBS = {!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFMAIN,$TEXMFLOCAL,!!$TEXMFDIST}
```

into the `texmf.cnf` returned by `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`, thus disabling database search in `$TEXMFLOCAL`.

Comment: A couple of issues with this: 1) The `texmf.cnf` file listed is `texlive/2011/texmf.cnf`, which I believe will be clobbered when the distribution is updated, 2) it breaks the documented behaviour of the `texlive` distribution that `TEXMFLOCAL` requires `ls-R`.  I want to minimize the impact and mystery for future sys-admins who may not be TeX-savy.  Is there some way of adding another tree that does not break behaviour and will be persistent between `texlive` updates?

Comment: `texlive/2011/texmf.cnf` will not be clobbered when you stay with TL11; since there is currently no supported way to upgrade a TL installation (TL11 -> TL12), you will have to move it manually to `texlive/2012/texmf.cnf`. If you want to manage a separate texmf-Tree, see [this discussion](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-February/031111.html).

Answer (score 2):

Martin's answer looks like the correct answer to your question, but I'd like to answer the question you didn't ask, but should have asked IMHO :-) And that question is: how do I allow someone to maintain `TEXMFLOCAL`?

You seem to assume that only the admin can update the `ls-R` file in `TEXMFLOCAL`. That's not the case. Anyone who can write to `TEXMFLOCAL` can update the file. If your users have enough privilege to update (rename) files in `TEXMFLOCAL`, they should already be able to update the `ls-R` file there without any problem. Just tell them to run `mktexlsr /path/to/texmflocal` instead of just `mktexlsr` if they want to avoid errors concerning the trees in which they cannot write, otherwise they can just ignore errors, `TEXMFLOCAL/ls-R` will be updated anyway.

That's the simple answer to how to share TeX Live administration privileges: just use the filesystem permissions.

(PS: if you current `ls-R` file is owned by root, you'll need to `chown` or `chgrp` and `chmod` it the first time.)

Comment: In principle this is a reasonable solution, but it requires the admins to create a separate group for just those users managing the packages (extra ongoing work for the sys-admins) and giving them the potential to "bring down the system" by messing up other packages if they leave the `ls-R` file in an incorrect state.  For this reason, broadening the permissions of the `ls-R` file are not considered acceptable.  (I am not the admin here, but a user trying to find as stable a solution as possible.)

Comment: @mforbes: IMHO, the right solution (tm) to your problem is to let users maintain their packages, each package in a separate location (independent of TEXMFLOCAL, and preferably under SVN or similar), and then let the admin run a cron job that syncs TEXMFLOCAL with these locations and runs mktexlsr $TEXMFLOCAL afterwards.